# How to activate the admin account of Discourse using the SSH console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, pry, discourse

I am trying to setup Discourse with one-click installer using droplet over Digital Ocean. I followed all the instructions and have correctly configured the SMTP details. But when I register for the admin account using the front-end installer, I am not able to receive the email.

I read a tutorial where it is mentioned that if the email doesn’t land in the mailbox, I can still activate the account and set the user as admin using the following commands using the console:

```
cd /var/discourse
sudo ./launcher enter app
rails c
user = User.find_by_email("<admin_email>")
user.admin = true
user.approved = true
user.save
EmailToken.confirm(user.email_tokens.first.token)
```

I am able to run the commands up to the fourth line. After running the fourth command, it finds and displays the user details. But I am not able to enter the next command. There’s this colon “:” and when I reach the end of the displayed details, “(END)” is written. I can’t type and run the further commands to activate the user.

After rails c, there’s this [1] pry (main) > thing. Please help me out on how to enter the next commands and activate the account.

Comment: Can you post the console output after the fourth command?

Answer (score 1):

For future travellers, this issue was discussed on the meta.discourse.org forum and [the following resolution](https://meta.discourse.org/t/activating-admin-account-from-console/79146/2) was suggested by Matt Palmer.

> When the colon appears, press q to get back to a prompt, and type the
>   next command.